# Detect if java is installed on the web server from php

Tags: java, php

Is it possible to detect from a php script if java is installed on the server (if I can run an exec() command with java)?

Thanks,

Benjamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you can run `exec` you should be able to use the cli detection of your choice like `which java`, `locate java` etc.. Im sure there are tons of methods to do this (the two i presented not necessarily the best).

Comment: `locate java` could return false positives if there are files on the f/s named "javascript" or similar.  `which` is a better choice, but it depends on the java binary to be in the system path.  I'm not sure either of these are great though.

Comment: @AJ: +1 - i forget the caveats with those commands as i generally dont use them in the context of a script to ensure existence of something. But my point is if he has access to `exec` there are all kinds potential avenues to take here, these being two possibilities. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Which one is less resource consuming if you have access to exec?

Comment: what about "java -version"  ?

Comment: @zmf: Well that would imply that `java` is on the path of the user calling php. Which it may or may not be. In order to get around that youd need to know the full path to `java` which would also mean that you already know java exists.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this:

```
$result = exec('command -v java >/dev/null && echo "yes" || echo "no"');
```

`$result` should be `yes` if the java command exists or `no` if it doesn't. You need a different command if you're running on Windows. Maybe something like:

```
$result = exec('java -version > NUL && echo yes || echo no');
```